# flash upload progess not showed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am writing this code to upload a file to server user flash , it send file to server , but it shows no progress ,

```
var _var1:String= '';

            var globalParam = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
            for (var element:String in globalParam) {
            if (element == 'host'){
            _var1 =   globalParam[element];
                }
            }


            if(_var1 != '')
            {
                var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_var1);
                req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
                req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                req.data = recorder.output;




                var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
                // set progress
                loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , fileUploadProgress);

                // set on complete
                loader.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA , fileUploadComplete);

                // set on error handler
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR , fileUploadIOError);

                // set on security error handler
                loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR , fileUploadSecurityHandler);

                // set on open
                loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN , fileUploadOpenHandler);

                //ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_progress_change" , String(0));
                function fileUploadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void{
                    var bytesTotal:uint = event.bytesTotal;
                    var bytesLoaded:uint = event.bytesLoaded;
                    var pctDone:Number = (bytesLoaded / bytesTotal) * 100;
                    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_progress_change" , String(pctDone));
                    //trace(bytesLoaded+ " / "+bytesTotal); 
                }


                // On open
                function fileUploadOpenHandler(event:Event):void{

                    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_started"); 
                }

                function fileUploadComplete(event:DataEvent):void{

                    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_finished" , String(event.currentTarget.size));; 
                }


                function fileUploadSecurityHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void{
                    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_securityproblem" , String(event.text));; 
                }


                function fileUploadIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
                    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_upload_ioproblem" , String(event.text));; 
                }
            }
```

when the file start for upload , fileOpenHandler reached , and after the end , I get 'infinity' in progress , I can not get any progress or on complete , where the problem with my code ?

Comment: Did you get the progress in the `trace` function?

Comment: yes , that is the same as something shows in javascript

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get progress events using URLLoader. The documentation at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:progress mentions this. If you want to receive progress events, you'll have to use another method to send your data across (although I don't know what that might be).

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

    public class URLLoaderProgress extends Sprite
    {
        public function URLLoaderProgress()
        {
            var loader:URLLoader;
            var request:URLRequest;
            var data:String;

            request = new URLRequest("http://example.com");
            request.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data += "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
            }

            loader = new URLLoader(request);
            loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function (e:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                trace(e.bytesLoaded);
            });

            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (e:Event):void
            {
                trace("complete");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. You can not access the data but it does give you progress.

Comment: Updated the answer with a barebones example. Only one progress event is fired, irrespective of the amount of data, and just before the complete event.

Comment: Functionally, none. I stripped out the external variable dependencies in your example and wrote a basic working program.